# Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception

Tags: php, elasticsearch, runtime-error, fatal-error

So I am using elasticsearch.

I have this code:

```
    <?php

     error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

  $hosts = [
    'http://localhost:80',        // SSL to localhost
];
$clientBuilder = ClientBuilder::create();   // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
$clientBuilder->setHosts($hosts);           // Set the hosts
$client = $clientBuilder->build();    
    $params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id',
    'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
];

$response = $client->index($params);
print_r($response);
```

I get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception:   405 Method Not Allowed

## Method Not Allowed

The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /my_index/my_type/my_id.

in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php:615 Stack trace: #0 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php(279): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process4xxError(Array, Array, Array) #1 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\react\promise\src\FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections{closure}(Array) #2 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\ringphp\src\Future\CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NU in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php on line 615

Comment: Strange you configure Elastic on the port 80. If you didnot change config, please give a try with 9200.

Comment: @LeBigCat What do you mean?

Comment: Elastic default port is 9200. If i right 80 is the apache one.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!
I just had to change

```
  $hosts = [
    'http://localhost:80',        // SSL to localhost
];
```

To

```
  $hosts = [
    'http://localhost:80'        // SSL to localhost
];
```

(remove the comma)